# JSON being parsed to type String, not type [String:Any] as required (Swift IOS)

Tags: ios, json, swift

So I am parsing a JSON and casting it as type [String:Any]. However, sometimes the resulting type is of type String and i am not sure why. Below is the code being used to convert JSON into a dictionary:

```
var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    let postString = ""
    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {
            //check for fundamental networking error
            print("error=\(error)")
            return
        }
        if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {
            //check for http errors
            print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
            print("response = \(response)")
        }
        _ = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!
        do{
            JSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! [String:Any]
            print(JSON)
        }
        catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
```

Now the weird part is that the following first JSON is being returned as type [String:Any], but the second JSON is being returned as type String only even though they are almost identical:

Type [String:Any]:

```
["state": Closed, "description": GLOBAL -  upgrade redirect not working, "severity": S3 - Medium, "products": Internal, "gmps": {
}, "type": INCIDENT, "Escalation": , "summary": , "serviceNames": <__NSSingleObjectArrayI 0x6100000165a0>(
Web Publishing
)
, "ticket": INC-136278, "ettr": , "SocialMedia": , "services": Development & Engineering, "InternalDetails": , "oss": Desktop, "sent": 2017-03-08 16:46:42, "regions": Global, "InternalActions": support teams performed controlled restarts of the affected service, "sirs": {
    "INC-136286" =     {
        CarriersNotified = "";
        ExternalName = "Web Publishing";
        ServiceImpact = "Content publishing will be unavailable on external website ";
        StateOfService = "No_Impact";
        downtime = 77;
        end = "2017-03-08 16:01:00";
        location = Global;
        region = Global;
        resource = "Web Publishing - Content/Redirects";
        sevicerecord = "SVC-679";
        sirActualDowntime = 77;
        sirEnd = "2017-03-08 16:01:00";
        sirPlannedDowntime = "<null>";
        sirStart = "2017-03-08 14:44:00";
        start = "2017-03-08 14:44:00";
        subsaffected = 1;
    };
}, "notificationSeverity": S3]
```

Type String:

```
["state": Closed, "description": GLOBAL - MSG - Multiple users reporting client disconnections/client removal on, "severity": S3 - Medium, "products": Internal, "gmps": {
}, "type": INCIDENT, "Escalation": , "summary": , "serviceNames": <__NSArrayI 0x6100000345e0>(
CORP,
SecureConnectPlus-CORP
)
, "ticket": INC-134786, "ettr": , "SocialMedia": , "services": Employee Connectivity & Productivity, "InternalDetails": , "oss": Android, BB10, iOS, "sent": 2017-03-07 15:39:36, "regions": Global, "InternalActions": support teams performed controlled restarts of the affected service, "sirs": {
    "INC-134792" =     {
        CarriersNotified = "";
        ExternalName = "CORP";
        ServiceImpact = "Administrators for Internal may be unable to manage devices from the BES administration console. Impacted employees may be unable to perform new device actions. In addition, they may be unable to perform self service tasks using the self service console. Also, employees may unable to request BB2FA/Strong Authentication pre-authentication (for their VPN).";
        StateOfService = "No_Impact";
        downtime = 29;
        end = "2017-02-28 15:55:00";
        location = Global;
        region = Global;
        resource = "Enterprise Service - Internal";
        sevicerecord = "SVC-1505";
        sirActualDowntime = 29;
        sirEnd = "2017-02-28 15:55:00";
        sirPlannedDowntime = "<null>";
        sirStart = "2017-02-28 15:26:00";
        start = "2017-02-28 15:26:00";
        subsaffected = 0;
    };
    "INC-134800" =     {
        CarriersNotified = "";
        ExternalName = "SecureConnectPlus-CORP";
        ServiceImpact = "employees with Android for Work (including Samsung KNOX) activated devices, may be unable to access internal resources (including Email, PIM, Intranet). with iOS devices using Connect Plus may be unable to browse intranet resources, or Secure Connect Plus dependent internal applications.";
        StateOfService = "No_Impact";
        downtime = 9934;
        end = "2017-03-07 13:00:00";
        location = Global;
        region = Global;
        resource = " BES - Secure Connect Plus - Internal";
        sevicerecord = "SVC-1515";
        sirActualDowntime = 9934;
        sirEnd = "2017-03-07 13:00:00";
        sirPlannedDowntime = "<null>";
        sirStart = "2017-02-28 15:26:00";
        start = "2017-02-28 15:26:00";
        subsaffected = "0.1";
    };`enter code here`
}, "notificationSeverity": S3]
```

Comment: if you try to doing with Type [String:AnyObject] it would be best for you

Comment: How have you checked _the second JSON is being returned as type String only_? I cannot find any parts checking the type of JSON in your code.

Comment: You might want to validate your json content first. Try this [site](http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/)